# SQL Merge not inserting new row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge

I am trying to use T-SQL `Merge` to check for the existence of records and update, if not then insert.

The update works fine, but the insert is not working.

Any and all help on this would be gratefully received.

```
DECLARE
    @OperatorID          INT         = 2,
    @CurrentCalendarView VARCHAR(50) = 'month';

WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.OperatorOption 
    WHERE OperatorID = @OperatorID
)
MERGE INTO OperatorOption AS T
USING CTE S ON T.OperatorID = S.OperatorID

WHEN MATCHED THEN 
   UPDATE 
       SET T.CurrentCalendarView = @CurrentCalendarView

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (OperatorID, PrescriptionPrintingAccountID, CurrentCalendarView)
    VALUES (@OperatorID, NULL, @CurrentCalendarView);
```

Comment: See my answer.  You were not using merge correctly.   You need to produce a row that does not match.  It thinks there is nothing to insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When would a row *Selected* from `OperatorOption` not already exist in `OperatorOption`?

If you're saying this code does not insert - you're right it doesn't because the row has to be there to begin with (in which case it won't insert), or the row is not there to begin with, in which case there is nothing in the source dataset to insert.

Does

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.OperatorOption 
WHERE OperatorID = @OperatorID
```

return anything or not?

This does not work the way you think it does. There is nothing in the source CTE.

The answer to 'was a blank dataset missing from the target' is 'No' so nothing is inserted

To do this operation, I use this construct:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.OperatorOption 
(OperatorID, PrescriptionPrintingAccountID, CurrentCalendarView)
SELECT @OperatorID, NULL, @CurrentCalendarView 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM dbo.OperatorOption 
    WHERE OperatorID = @OperatorID
    )
```

Comment: A row would not exists for a new user of the system.

Comment: when there are values in the table that match the @OperatorID yes it returns data which is why its doing the update, however when its not matched is should be doing the insert

Comment: Oh I see, you are using `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET`. I've never used it that way before

Comment: I used this only to see if it would work, and neither `WHEN  NOT MATCHED` AND `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET` both give 0 rows effected

Comment: `MERGE` is not built to do this. You're saying 'did you find nothing (that's whats in the source CTE) in the source? and the answer is: no - nothing was not missing from the source.

Comment: Youre right, ive just put this into a tmp table, and its worked, when passing this through in production i'll be passing this into a TVP anyway most likely. Im going to be upvoting this and marking as the answer to hopefully this will negate the issue

Comment: Merge will do this.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter you are inserting values as variables.  It thinks there is nothing to insert.

You need to produce data that does not match.

Like this:

```
DECLARE @OperatorID INT = 3, @CurrentCalendarView VARCHAR(50) = 'month';
declare @t table (operatorID int, CurrentCalendarView varchar(50));
insert into @t values (2, 'year');

MERGE @t AS TARGET
USING (SELECT @OperatorID, @CurrentCalendarView) AS source (operatorID, CurrentCalendarView)
   on (TARGET.operatorID = Source.operatorID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
   UPDATE SET TARGET.CurrentCalendarView = @CurrentCalendarView    
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (OperatorID, CurrentCalendarView)
    VALUES (source.OperatorID, source.CurrentCalendarView);

select * from @t
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert probably isn't working because your source CTE does not produce any rows. Depending on how your table is organised, you might need to select from some other source, or use [table valued constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to produce source data.

Comment: the CTE is producing data as the update works, but the insert effects 0 rows

Comment: The CTE shouldnt bring back any rows, which is why i want it to do the insert